# Pass an array from function and use it globally in other function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a `C()` function within a function `B()` within has another function `A()`; the function `A()` runs at each change of a drop-down. The `B()` function generates an array of two dimensions, `C ()` function takes the array of two dimension and generates another one of one dimension is the array `v []` generated, the issue is how to pass the array in `C()` and use it globally in a function named `calculate()` declared in the same level of `A()`?

I've heard global variables are bad, what alternative solution should I use?

```
A(){
  B(){
    C(){
      var v = new Array();
        .....
        .....
        v[i] = disciplines[i].nom;
       }
     }
   }
Calculate(array,id){
  var result = v[i];
}
```

I'm using codeigniter, in script2 i have a function that will calculate the amount to be paid and insert it into an input which have the id = salle_montant_paye, here i miss two variable : qp(the pourcentage % example=0.5) and tarif(the amount per month). So i need to passe them from script one to script two.

in script one for each choose of salle(gym) i have a discipline(sport) and for each discipline i have a qp(pourcentage) and tarif(amount) So the array qp[] and tarif[] genereted by the loop for, contain the values of qp and tarif by id, for instance if i choose football (that have the index 2 from the array discipline) on gym named Zimgym i must pay 120 per month and the society will pay for me the half(0.5). these values are stored in qp[i] and tarif[] that resulted on the loop for, so i need to passe them to the function $('#disciplines').change(function () { var a = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'); that have the index of discipline a = 2 that i will used to retrieve the value of qp and tarif and then passe them to the script 2 to calculate the amount to be paid.

My code :

**Script 1**

```
function qp(qp, id) {
    var qpresult = qp[id];
}

function tarif(tarif, id) {
    var tarifresult = tarif[id];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#salle').change(function () {
        //any select change on the dropdown with id salle trigger this code        
        $("#disciplines > option").remove(); //first of all clear select items
        var salle_nom = $('#salle').val(); //here i'm taking salle id of the selected one.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/public_html/admin/dropdown_salle/get_cities/" + salle_nom,
            //here i'm calling our user controller and get_disciplines method with the salle_id
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (disciplines) //we're calling the response json array 'disciplines'
            {
                var discipline = new Array();
                var qp = new Array();
                var tarif = new Array();
                for (i = 0; i < disciplines.length; ++i) {
                    // Now i got 3 arrays from the two dimentional 
                    //array from the db. one for 'disciplines',
                    // one for 'qp_agent' = (pourcentage a payé pour l'agent), 
                    //and the last for 'tarif'(tarif par mois de la cette discipline dans la salle choisi).
                    discipline[i] = disciplines[i].discipline + ' pour ' + disciplines[i].categorie_tarif;
                    qp[i] = disciplines[i].qp_agent;
                    tarif[i] = disciplines[i].tarif;
                }
                $.each(discipline, function (id, value)
                    //here i'm doing a foeach loop round each value
                    //with id as the key and value as the value
                    {
                        var opt = $('<option />');
                        // here i'm creating a new select option with for each value
                        opt.val(id);
                        opt.text(value);
                        $('#disciplines').append(opt);
                        //here i will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'disciplines'
                    });
            }
        });
    });
    var qp = new Array();

    // here on change disciplines i got the disciplines id, i will
    //use it to have 'qp' value and the 'tarif' value from qp[]
    //and tarif[] that correspond on discipline selected
    $('#disciplines').change(function () {
        var a = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
        //here i retrieve the qp and tarif value corresponds to my 'discipline' choosen.
        var qp = qp(qp, a);
        var tarif = tarif(tarif, a);
    });
});
 // in the end i must pass thes 2 variables qp and tarif to 
 //the seconde script in te same page that calculate the amount to be paid
```

**Script 2**

```
 function insertText(elemID) {
        var datestart = document.getElementById('date3');
        var dateend = document.getElementById('date4');
        var start = datestart.value;
        var end = dateend.value;
        var date1 = new Date(start);
        var date2 = new Date(end);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        var diffMonths = Math.round(diffDays / 30);
        var qp_variable = qp; // ici je doit affecter la valeur de qp passé a qp_variable
        var tarif_variable = tarif; // ici je doit affecter la valeur de qp passé a qp_variable
        var finalresult = diffMonths * qp_variable * tarif_variable;

        document.getElementById("salle_montant_paye").value = finalresult;
        //Now i get the js variable inside my input element.
    }
```

Comment: I tried to understand but either I'm too unfocused or I don't really get what you're trying to do. Instead of exaplaining in abstract ABCD-functions, can you explain what you have at the beginning and what you want in the end?

Comment: thanks for your answer.I'm using codeigniter, in script2 i have a function that will calculate the amount to be paid and insert it into an input which have the id = salle_montant_paye, here i miss two variable : qp(the pourcentage % example=0.5) and tarif(the amount per month). So i need to passe them from script one to script two.

Comment: in script one for each choose of salle(gym) i have a discipline(sport) and for each discipline i have a qp(pourcentage) and tarif(amount) So the array qp[] and tarif[] genereted by the loop for, contain the values of qp and tarif by id, for instance if i choose football (that have the index 2 from the array discipline) on gym named Zimgym i must pay 120 per month and the society will pay for me the half(0.5). these values are stored in qp[i] and tarif[] that resulted on the loop for,

Comment: so i need to passe them to the function $('#disciplines').change(function () {
var a = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'); 
that have the index of discipline a = 2 that i will used to retrieve the value of qp and tarif and then passe them to the script 2 to calculate the amount to be paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var app = {}, 
    app.qp = [],
    app.tarif = [];

$('#salle').change(function () {
    //any select change on the dropdown with id salle trigger this code        
    $("#disciplines > option").remove(); //first of all clear select items
    var salle_nom = $('#salle').val(); //here i'm taking salle id of the selected one.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/public_html/admin/dropdown_salle/get_cities/" + salle_nom,
        //here i'm calling our user controller and get_disciplines method with the salle_id
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (disciplines) //we're calling the response json array 'disciplines'
        {
            var discipline = [];                                                                           for (i = 0; i < disciplines.length; ++i) {
                // Now i got 3 arrays from the two dimentional 
                //array from the db. one for 'disciplines',
                // one for 'qp_agent' = (pourcentage a payé pour l'agent), 
                //and the last for 'tarif'(tarif par mois de la cette discipline dans la salle choisi).
                discipline[i] = disciplines[i].discipline + ' pour ' + disciplines[i].categorie_tarif;
                app.qp[i] = disciplines[i].qp_agent;
                app.tarif[i] = disciplines[i].tarif;
            }
            $.each(discipline, function (id, value)
                //here i'm doing a foeach loop round each value
                //with id as the key and value as the value
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />');
                    // here i'm creating a new select option with for each value
                    opt.val(id);
                    opt.text(value);
                    $('#cities').append(opt);
                    //here i will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'disciplines'
                });
        }
    });
});

// here on change disciplines i got the disciplines id, i will
//use it to have 'qp' value and the 'tarif' value from qp[]
//and tarif[] that correspond on discipline selected
$('#disciplines').change(function () {
    var a = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    //here i retrieve the qp and tarif value corresponds to my 'discipline' choosen.
    var qpValue = qp(qp, a);
    var tarifValue = tarif(tarif, a);
});

function qp(qp, id) {
   if (qp.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
       return qp[id]; 
   }
   return '';
}

function tarif(tarif, id) {
   if (tarif.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
       return tarif[id]; 
   }
   return '';
}
});
```

Comment: I've heard global variables are bad ? http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply pass `v` as an argument from `C` to `Calculate` function, like this:

```
A(){
  B(){
    C(){
      var v = new Array();
      .....
      .....
      v[i] = disciplines[i].nom;
      Calculate(v, i);
    }
  }
}

Calculate(array, id){
  var result = array[id];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i edited my post for more details please have a look.